# Mostrar title en un custom post de wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Buenas gente, resulta que tengo un custom post en donde hace tiempo se le quito el titulo que trae por defecto digamos pero lo hizo otra persona y ahora necesito agregarselo nuevamente pero no se como hacerlo, aqui pareceria que esta mostrandose pero no es asi. Algun conocedor de Wordpress que pueda ayudarme?

```js
function brc_do_and_dont_response_title_text( $title ) {
 $screen = get_current_screen();

 if ( 'do_and_dont' == $screen->post_type ) {
  $title = esc_attr__( 'Enter Name', 'fbb' );
 }

 return $title;
}

add_filter( 'enter_title_here', 'brc_do_and_dont_response_title_text' );
```

Answer (score 0):

[enter_title_here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/enter_title_here/) es un hook de WP y se utiliza para establecer el texto por defecto para los posts nuevos, solamente comentando la linea del add_filter alcanzaria, recuerda que la funcion brc_do_and_dont_response_title_text seria obsoleta luego de esto.

Comment: No Ale, sigue sin aparecer el campo para poner el titulo

Comment: esa pieza de codigo no se encarga de ocultarla, si no de ponerle u nvalor por defecto.

Comment: perdon, pero salio el enter sin querer.

te queria decir que enter_title_here solo se encarga del placeholder, no de ocultarlo.
podrias verificar que no este ningun estilo CSS ocultando el campo titulo del editor de post?